# SQL How to Count Number of Specific Values in a Row

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a table that has 50 Fields. 20 of those fields can contain the Value "YES" "NO" or "N/A". How do I query the number of "YES"s for a given row?

Comment: That's one reason why you should normalize your tables.

Comment: Think of this table as a Survey with 20 Questions that are answered "YES" "NO" or "N/A".
Each row of the table is a users response to a survey. Can you provide a brief example to illustrate how to normalize this to better achieve the desired results?

Comment: Then you should create a table `Survey` (with a `SurveyID`, a `UserID` and  whatever you need) and a table `Question`(with the text). Another table `Result` contains the `YES`, `NO`,`N/A` and a third table  `SurveyQuestion` with `SurveyID`,`QuestionID` and `ResultID`(nullable to support unanswered questions) as foreign-keys to link all tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You write a long statement that adds up the values:

```
select ((case when value1 = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when value2 = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) +
        . . .
        (case when value50 = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as NumYesses
```

This would be much easier if you normalized the data, so each value was in a separate row.  You would do this by having a separate table, called a junction or association table.

Also, you can generate this code in a spreadsheet, such as Excel, by using formulas on the columns names (or by writing a query that uses metadata in your database).

Note:  this is generic ANSI SQL, because you don't specify the database.  There may be some shortcuts to writing the code in different databases.